# efficient way to create map of lists in functional style

Tags: f#

Given a dataset, for example a CSV file that might look like this:

```
x,y
1,2
1,5
2,1
2,2
1,1
...
```

I wish to create a map of lists containing the y's for a given x... The result could look like this:

```
{1:[2,5,1], 2:[1,2]}
```

In python this would be straight forward to do in an imperative manner.. and would probably look somewhat like this:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for x,y in csv_data:
    d[x].append(y)
```

**How would you go about achieving the same using functional programming techniques in F#?**
Is it possible to do it as short, efficient and concise *(and read-able)* as in the given python example, using only functional style?, or would you have to fall back to imperative programming style with mutable data structures..?

*Note: this is not a homework assignment, just me trying to wrap my head around functional programming*

***EDIT: My conclusion based on answers thus far***

I tried timing each of the provided answers on a relative big csv file, just to get a feeling of the performance.. Furthermore I did a small test with the imperative approach:

```
let res = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
for row in l do
    if (res.ContainsKey(fst row) = false) then 
        res.[fst row] <- new List<string>()
    res.[fst row].Add(snd row)
```

The imperative approach completed in ~0.34 sec.

I think that the answer provided by Lee is the most general FP one, however the running time was ~4sec.

The answer given by Daniel ran in ~1.55sec.

And at last the answer given by jbtule ran in ~0.26. (I find it very interesting that it beat the imperative approach)

I used 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()' for timing, and the code is executed as F# 3.0 in .Net 4.5

*EDIT2: fixed stupid error in imperative f# code, and ensured that it uses the same list as the other solutions*

Comment: In regards to speed it's more about the Data Structure than the small amount of code to create it. `Map` (Balanced Tree), `Dictionary` (Mutable HashTable), `Lookup` (Non Mutable HashTable), they all have different characteristics especially related to size of data you put in them.  Also, you shouldn't just time creation, because there very likely may be trade offs with faster creation and slower value lookups.

Comment: I actually assumed that Maps where hash tables in FP.. Nice to know that they actually are balanced trees.. So obviously Maps must have slower lookup times, O(log n) or something like that.

Comment: You can improve the imperative version even further: http://dotnetfiddle.net/T3DUDV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let addPair m (x, y) =
    match Map.tryFind x m with
    | Some(l) -> Map.add x (y::l) m
    | None -> Map.add x [y] m

let csv (pairs : (int * int) list) = List.fold addPair Map.empty pairs
```

Note this adds the `y` values to the list in reverse order

Comment: I wonder if this solution would put a lot of stress on the garbage collector, -if it is the case that a new Map object is created for each entry in the csv file..?

Comment: @Mitzh - I don't think so - maps are probably implemented as balanced binary trees where each new map shares nodes with the old one.

Comment: I just tested both this solution and Daniels on a relative big csv file, and measuring the time with 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()'.. I expected that this one would be the fastest, but the results I got shows that this one is actually slower than Daniels.. (~4sec for this solution and ~1.5 for Daniels)

Comment: @Mitzh - If you look at the implementation of `groupBy` it uses mutable lists and dictionaries internally so it's not surprising it's faster. The other answers are more idiomatic F# but this demonstrates a more direct 'functional style'.

Comment: @Mitzh - The F# compiler is open source and you can find the implementation of `groupBy` at https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs

Answer (score 7):

```
[
  1,2
  1,5
  2,1
  2,2
  1,1
]
|> Seq.groupBy fst
|> Seq.map (fun (x, ys) -> x, [for _, y in ys -> y])
|> Map.ofSeq
```

Comment: If you're okay with a map of sequences, then the list comprehension can be shortened to `Seq.map snd ys`.

Comment: I really like the conciseness of this solution... However, doesn't this potentially iterate the data set 3 times?

Answer (score 2):

use LINQ in F#, LINQ is functional.

```
open System.Linq

let data =[
  1,2
  1,5
  2,1
  2,2
  1,1
]

let lookup = data.ToLookup(fst,snd)

lookup.[1] //seq [2;5;1]
lookup.[2] //seq [1;2
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as using `Seq.groupBy`.

Comment: But it is doing the Hashtable and element transformation in one pass.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that is nice.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, an implementation using a query expression:

```
let res =
    query { for (k, v) in data do
            groupValBy v k into g
            select (g.Key, List.ofSeq g) }
    |> Map.ofSeq
```